# Error al guardar datos usando EF ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo la siguiente tabla en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que estoy haciendo un post para guardar tanto el codigo como el nombre del cliente usando EF

**CONTROLADOR**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Clientes(Cliente cc)
 {
    string codigo = cc.codigoCliente;
    string nombre = cc.nombreCliente;
    miClie.guardarCliente(codigo, nombre);
    return View();
 }
```

**MODELO**

```
public void guardarCliente(string cc, string nn)
{
    var lista = new Cliente
    {
        codigoCliente = cc,
        nombreCliente = nn
    };
    using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
    {
      ctx.Entry(lista).State = EntityState.Added;
      ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

El asunto es que la `var lista` me aparece con el valor de `idCliente=0`cuando yo no he especificado ningún valor para el, puesto que es un campo autoincrementado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al final me lanza una excepción:

> SqlException: No se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de
>   identidad de la tabla 'Clientes' cuando IDENTITY_INSERT es OFF.

Cual es mi error en mi codigo (puesto que siempre he empleado el mismo codigo para insertar datos en una tabla)

Comment: Esto significa que deseas agregar un dato en una columna que se autoincrement. Posiblemente el `codigoCliente`. Para solucionarlo tendrás que omitir el código del cliente para que se autoincremente de manera automático o en su caso, cambiar la estructura de tu tabla para que no sea un campo `IDENTITY`, es decir, que no se autoincremente

Comment: o cambiar la definicion de la clase cliente y permitir nulos?

Comment: Pero se puede asignar `IDENTITY` a un `varchar`? eso no lo sabía...

Comment: @Phi `codigoCliente`es un varchar, el unico campo que se autoincrementa es el `ìdCliente`que es un int

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ni yo lo sabia

Comment: Por eso me parece raro que te sugieran que **codigoCliente** es el problema... y otra cosa, es que al momento de agregar un item a la BD es normal que el id autoincremental lo cree 0, no debería ser problema =/

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera dado que su campo se llama códigoCliente, asumía que ese pudiera ser el problema ya que no se muestran más datos al respecto, no obstante, como indica el OP que es de tipo `VARCHAR` entonces el problema va con el con campo `idCliente`, de alguna manera está recibiendo un valor y eso no es permitido para un campo de tipo `IDENTITY`

Comment: @Baker1562 porque utilizas `ctx.Entry(lista).State = EntityState.Added;` en desmedro de `db.Add(entidad)`?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera costumbre, si un proyecto X use ese metodo siempre lo uso para los demas, reutilizo codigo digamos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso la columna no sigue las `convenciones` que define `entity framework`, por lo tanto no detecta automaticamente cual es la columna key de la tabla.

Para que la detecte cambia la columna por ejemplo a: ClienteID

Ahora bien sino lo quieres cambiar debes configurarlo, indicando cual es la key

```
public class ModelContext: DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().HasKey(t => t.idCliente).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

es asi como se indica que la propiedad es la key y ademas es identity

No debes ponerle el sufijo "Cliente" a cada columna de la tabla, es esa de mas, con solo definir las columnas codigo y nombre alcanza

Agunos otros detalles

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    public string codigo {get;set;}
    public string nombre {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Clientes(ClienteModel cc)
 {
    miClie.guardarCliente(cc);
    return View();
 }


public void guardarCliente(ClienteModel cc)
{
    var cliente = new Cliente
    {
        codigo = cc.codigo,
        nombre = cc.Nombre
    };

    using (var ctx = new ModelContext())
    {
      ctx.Cliente.Add(cliente);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

no pases por parametro cada valor, usa clase que definas como model de asp.net mvc

Comment: pregunta, yo primero cree la tabla y despues usando el template "Code First" la agregue al proyecto, si hago algun cambio en la base de datos usando SSMS, hay alguna forma de refrescar el modelo sin la necesidad de botar los archivos y volver a crearlos?

Comment: porque eliminar el archivo, para nada, si cambias el nombre de una columna busca la propiedad equivalente y tambien lo cambias, edita codigo, no tienes que borrar nada

Comment: hablo en general, por ejemplo, tengo que agregar nuevas tablas mas adelante, entonces queria saber si existe una forma de hacer un "update" del modelo sin necesidad de eliminar y agregar

Comment: Si primero creas la tabla y luego el código, es Database First...

Comment: Existe.. simplemente vas a tu modelo **edmx** y en el diagrama haces click derecho, en la ventana que se despliega aparece la opción "Actualizar modelo desde base de datos" o al parecido, no lo recuerdo literalmente...

Comment: Sí, se puede hacer un update desde el modelo EDMX. Click derecho, update from database

Comment: @Baker1562 mira este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY saludos :D

Comment: que edmx, si estamos hablando de Code First ? las actualizaciones se realizan en codigo directo, si actualizas la db luego vas al codigo y lo actualizas tambien, cualquier wizard que tenga Code First es para aplicar la primera vez, despues debes codificar a mano